# How to remove plugin jars on Eclipse plugin unistallation?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

I have created an Eclipse plugin. After installation it adds plugin jars `ui` and `core` in the plugins folder of Eclipse. But when I uninstall that plugin from the "*About Eclipse*" dialog it does not delete those jars from Eclipse plugin folder.

And when I try to install new version of the plugin it does not overwrite the old jars.

I don't want to remove it manually every time. How can I make those jars be removed from the plugins folder of Eclipse after uninstallation?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues w/uninstalling some plugins due to the fact that sometimes they are tightly integrated with each other.  Try this method.  It worked for me.  Write down the plugins you DO want and then simply wipe out all of Eclipse directory and reinstall.  As an additional step, I delete any .metadata files in each project in the workspace and then simply reimport them after the install.